# Possible to move my Areca 1880i raid-6 from a windows to Ubuntu Server without data loss?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I have a running windows 10 setup with Areca 1880i raid-6 with 10 disk connected. I want to drop windows and migrate to ubuntu running docker for my apps.

Is it possible to do this without losing all my data on my current raid-6 array?

Comment: If the RAID controller is presenting to the host os a single "drive" that represents your volume, it should be fine.  Of course, you can boot with a livecd to test it. Be a good time to check and test backup/restore systems too.